# Is glib thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, glib

I couldn't find any information in the glib documentation about thread safety.  I guess that means I should probably assume that it's NOT thread safe, but I'm unsure about what shared resources I should be locking around.

Does anybody have any experience with thread safety using glib?  What guidelines can I use to make sure my glib code is thread safe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Actually the glib reference manual is full of information about thread safety:

> After calling g_thread_init(), GLib is completely thread safe (all
>   global data is automatically locked), but individual data structure
>   instances are not automatically locked for performance reasons. So,
>   for example you must coordinate accesses to the same GHashTable from
>   multiple threads. The two notable exceptions from this rule are
>   GMainLoop and GAsyncQueue, which are threadsafe and need no further
>   application-level locking to be accessed from multiple threads.

You might want to take a look at [threads section](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-Threads.html) of the reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

Global policy is simple: all are threadsafe with exception of data manipulation funcs. Read there: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-programming.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [GLib reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html) you can get the following statement:

> GLib itself is internally completely thread-safe (all global data is automatically locked), but individual data structure instances are not automatically locked for performance reasons.

So to complement the previous answers, you don't need to call `g_thread_init()`.